# Windows 10 Shut Down dialog: switch default option from 'Switch user' back to 'Shut down'

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, dialog

Since about two weeks, pressing Alt-F4 on the desktop no long offers 'Shut down' as the default action. Instead, it shows 'Switch user' on top:

[image: Windows 10 Shut Down dialog]

So I can no longer just press Alt-F4 and press return, which is annoying.

Strangely, it also always shows 'Update and restart' in the option dropdown, even when no updates are scheduled:

[image: Windows 10 Shut Down dialog with dropdown open]

Now that I think about it, I wonder why it doesn't offer 'Hiberate' as an option, because I do have that enabled. So clearly, that dialog somehow got messed up.

I already found [this article](https://winaero.com/blog/set-default-action-shutdown-dialog-windows-10/) that shows a registry hack to revert the default action back to 'Shut Down', but it has no effect. I also tried choosing that 'Update and restart' option to see whether it would disappear, but it does not -- and in any case, 'Switch user' is still on top and default.

What might be causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'd recommend trying the solutions in [Power Options Missing from Start Menu in Windows 10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/power-options-missing-windows-10).  For adding Hibernate, see [How to Add or Remove Hibernate from Power Menu in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7445-add-remove-hibernate-power-menu-windows-10-a.html).  FYI: Hibernate only works the way it was intended (i.e. fast resume) with certain hardware configurations.  If you have an SSD, ensure Fast Startup is disabled (within BIOS/EFI and the OS), else it will slow down reboots and resuming from hibernation.

Comment: I noticed after the last time I restarted my computer to install updates recently, it rearranged the menu on me as well. I could do Win-D, ArrowUp, Enter to go into Sleep mode before.